# Button cannot press, no event occur

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make buttons for my game project as I followed tutorial from Youtube but when it comes to the button part, mine cannot do as expected.

I had try to find solutions from other videos and google search but still havent solve my problem yet. I had check as what they said like checking event system, if button is interactable, and  enable raycast hit but none of this becoming my button's problem.

Buttons:
[image: Buttons]

Button Inspector:
[image: Button Inspector]

Hierarchy:
[image: Hierarchy]

Canvas:
[image: Canvas]

Comment: That OnClick target on your inspector is definitely not right, go check it out.

Comment: You havent told it to do anything onclick

Comment: Each button I had add the event, but yet still havent work..........